# Oracle db and pl/sql cursor group with result

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, procedure

Good day, everyone!
I have question with my oracle db procedure:
(I apologize, for my English and unclear speech)
I wrote simple procedure (but even don't compile it, so i don't know work is it or no), but i don't like it, cos selec in loop.
Sometime age i wrote some sql selections with group by and result. So it's possible and how can i (in pl/sql) working with result.
P.s. Sorry, if it was and stupid, but i don't know, what i must write in google.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getDescription
(
        columnName IN VARCHAR2
)
AS
        CURSOR descriptionSelector IS
        SELECT utc.table_name tableName, utc.data_type columnType, utc.DATA_LENGTH columnLenth
        FROM user_tab_columns utc
        WHERE utc.column_name = columnName;

        fetched descriptionSelector%ROWTYPE;
        index INTEGER;
BEGIN
        index := 1;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad('No.',4)||rpad('Column',25)||rpad('Table',25)||rpad('Attribute',50));
        FOR currentSelect IN descriptionSelector
        LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rpad(index ,4) || ' ' ||rpad(columnName, 25)||' ' ||rpad(currentSelect.tableName,25)||' '||rpad('TYPE: '||currentSelect.columnType,20)' '||lpad('('||currentSelect.columnLenth||')',3));
                FOR secondSelection IN (
                        SELECT ref_ucc.table_name tableName, ref_ucc.column_name referenceColumnName, ref_ucc.constrain t_name
                        FROM user_cons_columns ucc
                        JOIN user_constraints uc
                                ON ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                        JOIN user_cons_columns ref_ucc
                                ON uc.r_constraint_name = ref_ucc.constraint_name
                        WHERE uc.constraint_type = 'R'
                        AND ucc.table_name = currentSelect.tableName
                        AND ucc.column_name = columnName)
                LOOP
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Constr: '||secondSelection.constraint_name||' References '||secondSelection.tableName||'('||secondSelection.referenceColumnName||')');
                END LOOP;
                index := index + 1;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: It is not clear what you need. Please provide actual question, best with some sample data and expected output.

Comment: Your procedure does not return any data, other than printing stuff to dbms_output.  What do you want to return?

Comment: I don't need any return. I want to convert this procedure with second select in loop, to only one select, when declare cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ref_ucc.table_name tableName, ref_ucc.column_name referenceColumnName, ref_ucc.constrain t_name
FROM user_cons_columns ucc
JOIN user_constraints uc
        ON ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
JOIN user_cons_columns ref_ucc
        ON uc.r_constraint_name = ref_ucc.constraint_name
WHERE uc.constraint_type = 'R'
AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT  1
        FROM  user_tab_columns utc
        WHERE utc.column_name = columnName
        AND   ucc.table_name = utc.tableName
    )
AND ucc.column_name = columnName
```